# How to retrieve the head and tail of a tuple in F#

Tags: f#, tuples

1. How do I retrieve the head and tail of a tuple in F#?

   For example `Conj (a, b)`, the head is `Conj`, tail is `(a, b)`.
2. I want to recursively run `buildtree` function on each parameters, put the head as `Node`'s element, where is the map in F#?

   ```
   let rec getparams = map List.head (List.tail getparams);

   type Elem = Prop
   type Tree = E | T of Elem * Tree * Tree

   let rec buildtree vars = function
       | E = head vars
       | T = buildtree (getparams vars)
   ```

After updated:

```
open System
open Microsoft.FSharp.Reflection
// Learn more about F# at http://fsharp.net
//type Prop = {a: string; b: string}
//let Prop a b = (a, b) 
type Op = Prop
type tree = E | T of Op * tree * tree
let tree x y z = (x, y, z)

type binOp = Conj | Disj | Impl 
type expr =   
| Prop of string   
| BinOp of binOp * expr * expr 
| Conj of expr * expr
| Disj of expr * expr
| Impl of expr * expr

type Prop = {a: string}
let Prop a = (a)

//type Conj = {a : Prop; b : Prop} 
let Conj a b = (a, b)

//type Conj_Int = {a : Prop; b : Prop} 
let Conj_Int a b = Conj a b
//type Conj_Elmin1 = {a : Conj}
let Conj_Elmin1 a = fst a
//type Conj_Elmin2 = {a : Conj}
let Conj_Elmin2 a = snd a

//type Impl = {a : Prop; b : Prop} 
let Impl a b = (a b)
//type Impl_Int = {assume : Prop; b : Prop} 
let Impl_Int assume b = Impl assume b
//type Impl_Elmin = {a :string; b : Impl}
let Impl_Elmin a b = if a = fst b then snd b

type Neg = {a : Prop;}
let Neg a = (a)

//type Double_Neg_Int = {a : Prop;}
let Double_Neg_Int a = Neg(Neg(a))

//type Double_Neg_Elmin = {a : Prop}
let Double_Neg_Elmin a = fst(fst(a))

//type Disj = {a : Prop; b : Prop} 
let Disj a b = (a,b)

//type Disj_Int1 = {a : Prop; b : Prop} 
let Disj_Int1 a b = (a b)
//type Disj_Int2 = {a : Prop; b : Prop} 
let Disj_Int2 a b = (a b)

//type Disj_Elmin1 = {a : Disj}
let Disj_Elmin1 a = fst(a)
//type Disj_Elmin2 = {a : Disj}
let Disj_Elmin2 a = snd(a)

type TupleSplitter = static member splitTuple (a,b,c) = (a,(b,c)) 

let tupleToList t = if Microsoft.FSharp.Reflection.FSharpType.IsTuple(t.GetType()) then Some (Microsoft.FSharp.Reflection.FSharpValue.GetTupleFields t |> Array.toList) else None
    let operation x = List.head(List.ofSeq(FSharpValue.GetTupleFields(x)))
let parameters x = List.tail(List.ofSeq(FSharpValue.GetTupleFields(x)))


let rec map f = function | Prop _ as t -> f t | BinOp(op, a, b) -> f(BinOp(op, map f a, map f b))
(*
let rec map f = function   
| Prop _ as t -> f t   | Conj(a, b) -> f(Conj(map f a, map f b))   
| Disj(a, b) -> f(Disj(map f a, map f b))   
| Impl(a, b) -> f(Impl(map f a, map f b)) 
*)
let buildtree vars expr = map (function Prop v -> Map.find v vars | expr -> expr) expr 

let t = buildtree(Conj("a","b"))
```

1. how to have two type of expression Op*Tree*Tree and Op*Tree?

Comment: Tuple doesn't have the concept for head and tail, so basically you can't do that. List have head and tail

Comment: In the version after the update, your `let Conj a b` defines a function that takes a function `a` and a value `b` and applies the function `a` to a value `b`. That's probably not what you wanted. Can you explain what is it supposed to do? (It could be just a misunderstanding of some syntax...)

Comment: @種瓜得瓜種豆得豆: XY problem; you're asking the wrong question. What is the actual problem you are trying to solve? What is the actual program you are trying to write?

Comment: updated code, i am trying to do derivation

Comment: i am still learning from a book called logic in computer science, but so far i find no algorithm in it, it only said change to normal form and then go a linear or SAT solver, do not know how it know when to use introduction or elimination

Comment: I still cannot understand what your `buildtree` function is trying to do. Can you describe the problem you are trying to solve? Failing that, can you describe the type you think your `buildtree` function will have, or at least what the type of `vars` will be?

Comment: i am still trying buildtree, actually building a tree recursively, first parameter is put on the left side, second is put on right side, as i do not know logic priority, i guess recursively run all the tuples then form a tree

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A tuple is defined as (exp1,exp2, ... ,expn) for example (1,"2",'3').
I can't see this pattern in your code.

If you use (exp1 exp2) it means function application (apply exp2 as first argument to function exp1).
The error you see on your code is because you defined Conj as a function accepting a function as first paramenter and you passed a string ("a") instead of a function.

If your question is how to split a tuple in head and tail you can go for the dynamic approach Tomas just explained, it will work for any n-tuple but you'll lose type information.

Otherwise the strong type solution is simply based on pattern matching:

```
let splitTuple (a,b,c) = (a,(b,c))
// Usage
let (head,tail) = splitTuple (1,"2",'3')
```

And if you want to make it work for n-tuples you'll have to define one overload for each n:

```
type TupleSplitter =
  static member splitTuple (a,b,c) = (a,(b,c))
  static member splitTuple (a,b,c,d) = (a,(b,c,d))
  static member splitTuple (a,b,c,d,e) = (a,(b,c,d,e))
// ... more overloads, as much as you need

// Usage
let (head,tail) = TupleSplitter.splitTuple (1,"2",'3',4.0)
// val tail : string * char * float = ("2", '3', 4.0)
// val head : int = 1
```

Answer (score 6):

As Ankur said, you can't get head and tail of a tuple - these operations are designed for processing functional lists that have arbitrary length and cannot be define for tuples that have a length known at compile time. If you want data with arbitrary length, you should probably use tuples and pattern matching (or `List.head` and `List.tail`).

If you really need to process tuples dynamically, you can use F# reflection:

```
open Microsoft.FSharp.Reflection

(1,2,3)
|> FSharpValue.GetTupleFields // Get fields of tuple as an array
|> List.ofSeq                 // Convert array to a list
|> List.tail                  // Now you can process list using head/tail
```

However, note that reflection is generally a bit slow and it should only be used when you need it (i.e. when writing some code that is dynamic and can't be written in any other way).

Comment: Any other way better than using reflection in this case, i am using for logic expression tree, by the way, which web tell the priority of logic operation such as conjuntion, implication? in F#, does it need to use stack and priority to do this expression tree?

Comment: @種瓜得瓜種豆得豆 I'm not sure I fully understand - are you interested in parsing a string that contains some logical formula, such as "Conj(A, Negation(B))"? Or do you use F# tuples to represent the data somehow?

Comment: it is not a string, i have updated in question, it is custom type

Comment: @種瓜得瓜種豆得豆 `let Conj a b = (a b)` should be `let Conj a b = (a,b)`

Answer (score 4):

You seem to be trying to replicate Haskell syntax and semantics in F#. Don't do that. Look at existing ML code and learn how to solve your problem idiomatically. In other words, your question is an XY problem: you're asking the wrong question.

Without knowing what problem you are trying to solve, it is difficult to answer your question but my best guess is:

```
type Expr = 
  | Prop of string
  | Conj of Expr * Expr
  | Disj of Expr * Expr
  | Impl of Expr * Expr

let deConj = function
  | Conj(a, b) -> a, b
  | _ -> invalidArg "expr" "deConj"
```

Perhaps you want to write a `map` over your `expr` type:

```
let rec map f = function
  | Prop _ as t -> f t
  | Conj(a, b) -> f(Conj(map f a, map f b))
  | Disj(a, b) -> f(Disj(map f a, map f b))
  | Impl(a, b) -> f(Impl(map f a, map f b))
```

Another solution is to rewrite your type to factor out the operators:

```
type binOp = Conj | Disj | Impl
type expr =
  | Prop of string
  | BinOp of binOp * expr * expr

let rec map f = function
  | Prop _ as t -> f t
  | BinOp(op, a, b) -> f(BinOp(op, map f a, map f b))
```

**EDIT**

I am not sure what your `buildtree` function is supposed to do but if it is evaluating expressions then perhaps you want something like this:

```
let buildtree vars expr =
  map (function Proj v -> Map.find v vars | expr -> expr) expr
```

This will map one expression to another, replacing `Proj v` with the corresponding expression (i.e. value of the variable `v`) given by `vars`.

Comment: i do not well understand these code, i updated code in question

Comment: when i try to let m5 = Conj "a" "b" why this value is not a function?

Comment: @種瓜得瓜種豆得豆: Looks like you're trying to use Haskell-style curried type constructors. MLs like F# do not curry their type constructors (they are not functions). You just do `Conj(a, b)` to construct a value of the `expr` type and then use the (identical) pattern `Conj(a, b)` to destructure it again.

Comment: @種瓜得瓜種豆得豆: You don't want to define lots of record types like `type Conj = {a : Prop; b : Prop}`. Just use the `Conj` type constructor from your `expr` type directly. Also, you need to be careful of shadowing existing record field names, e.g. your `Conj` record type defines a `b` but then your `Conj_Int` record type supercedes it with a different `b`.